# How to test the Public Static Void Main method in Java using JUnit 5?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, junit5

I want to take inputs in the main method , then pass to another that returns a value back to main and print the returned value in main method. I want to do this using JUnit 5.

(I am new to JUnit 5, so, would really appreciate the help.)

Comment: Test Main method is no different than test a normal static method. So I don't know what you want to achieve here.

Answer (score 1):

It is considered bad to test static methods because complex static methods themselves are bad and anti-OOP.

You can instead write your logic in a separate class, instantiate an instance of it in your main and use its method.

Then with JUnit 5, test the class' method by instantiating that class and using the method.